# Why am I unable to uninstall my VS 2010 Professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm unable to repair my VS 2010 Professional. I also can't uninstall.

The logs for the failed uninstall can be found [here](http://banico.org/dd_error_vs_procore_100.txt).

```
[12/07/11,13:33:31] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/07/11,13:33:31] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/07/11,13:36:54] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[12/07/11,13:37:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU is not installed.
[12/07/11,13:40:41] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/07/11,13:40:41] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/07/11,13:48:27] TFS Object Model (x64): [2] dlmgr: IBackgroundCopyError::GetErrorDescription failed: hr= 0x80073afc
[12/07/11,14:25:08] Microsoft .NET Framework 4: [2] Error code 9 for this component means "The storage control block address is invalid.
"
[12/07/11,14:25:09] Microsoft .NET Framework 4: [2] Component Microsoft .NET Framework 4 returned an unexpected value.
[12/07/11,14:25:09] Microsoft .NET Framework 4: [2] Return from system messaging: The storage control block address is invalid.

[12/07/11,14:26:07] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] CRootComponent::Install(): Cannot install; setup files failed verification.
[12/07/11,14:26:07] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_INVALID returned in CRootComponent::Install; the following file is invalid: C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Temp\30319.01\1033\VS_PRO\vs_setup.msi
[12/07/11,14:37:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 4 is not installed.
[12/07/11,14:37:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU is not installed.
[12/07/11,18:48:54] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/07/11,18:48:54] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/07/11,19:12:16] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/07/11,19:12:17] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/07/11,19:15:25] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[12/07/11,19:30:21] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU is not installed.
[12/07/11,19:38:36] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/07/11,19:38:36] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/07/11,19:54:03] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/07/11,19:54:03] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/07/11,19:57:55] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[12/07/11,20:14:38] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU is not installed.
[12/07/11,22:05:34] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/07/11,22:05:34] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/07/11,22:07:13] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[12/07/11,22:07:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU is not installed.
[12/07/11,22:08:24] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/07/11,22:08:24] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/07/11,22:10:45] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[12/07/11,22:10:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU is not installed.
[12/07/11,22:10:49] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[12/07/11,22:10:50] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[12/07/11,22:10:50] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[12/07/11,22:10:50] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[12/07/11,22:10:50] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
[12/07/11,22:10:50] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
[12/07/11,22:11:58] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/07/11,22:11:58] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/07/11,22:13:43] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/07/11,22:13:43] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/07/11,22:15:34] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[12/07/11,22:15:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU is not installed.
[12/07/11,22:17:02] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/07/11,22:17:02] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/07/11,22:22:04] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[12/07/11,22:22:27] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU is not installed.
[12/07/11,22:49:55] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/07/11,22:49:55] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/07/11,23:02:22] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[12/07/11,23:03:00] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU is not installed.
[12/08/11,01:32:36] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/08/11,01:32:36] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/08/11,01:44:23] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[12/08/11,01:45:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU is not installed.
[12/08/11,07:09:19] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/08/11,07:09:19] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/08/11,07:31:27] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/08/11,07:31:27] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/08/11,07:35:05] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[12/08/11,07:35:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU is not installed.
[12/08/11,08:09:00] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/08/11,08:09:00] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/08/11,08:10:56] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[12/08/11,08:11:13] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU is not installed.
[12/08/11,08:13:12] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #QFE.cab
[12/08/11,08:13:12] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] UpdateFileFetcherFromMsi: Warning: Missing fwlink entry for cabinet: #SP.cab
[12/08/11,08:15:12] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[12/08/11,08:15:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU is not installed.
```

Comment: Have you tried to just re-install it?

Comment: I'm unable to uninstall, so I couldn't reinstall.

Comment: Can you try a system restore to before it was installed?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've had my VS 2010 Professional for quite some time now. It had a lot of add ons that I recently uninstalled. And then tried applying SP1 which failed. Since then, I've been trying to repair or uninstall my VS 2010.

Comment: Have you tried using something like CCleaner?

Comment: Try using [Revo Uninstaller Free](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html).  Even if it doesn't uninstall the actual program, Revo will go on to search your entire computer for *all* traces of VS, so that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the VS 2010 uninstall utility?

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall

Comment: Yes I have tried that too. It says it has successfully uninstalled, but when I run the VS 2010 installer, it says it's still "there".

Comment: I have done that and then deleted the VS 2010 folder, cleared registries using a tool, and it still thinks there is VS 2010 installed. Why is that?

Comment: The files that it's complaining about in your temp directory (C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Temp)... do they exist even when you're not running setup?  If they exist, maybe delete them?

Comment: I raised the same question at Microsoft support and was advised to simply reinstall Windows. I was due for a harddisk upgrade anyway so I did. Thanks for all the replies.